# hide browser scrollbar on certain block

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scrollbar

Here is my problem.

```
<aside class="fixed-col">
<div class="fix-wrap cf">
    <div class="fixed-col-inner">
        <h1>lorem</h1>
        <div class="menu-button">
            <a href="#" onclick="return false"></a>
        </div><!-- menu-button -->
        <input type="text" id="search" placeholder="...">
        <button class="search-button"></button>
        <div class="fav-wrap">
            <a href="#" class="fav">ipsum (0)</a>
        </div><!-- fav-wrap -->
        <div class="menu-side">
            <img src="img/userpic.png" height="31" width="31" alt="">
            <a href="#" class="username">xxx xxx</a>
            <a href="#" class="logout">xxx</a>
            <ul class="main-nav">
                <li><a href="#">lorem</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="add">ipsum</a></li>
                <li class="last-li"></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="second-nav">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">HOVER ME AND SEE</a>
                    <div class="hidden-nav">
                    </div><!-- hidden-nav -->
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">amet</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- menu-side -->
        <ul class="social">
            <li class="facebook"><a href="#"></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- fixed-col-inner -->
    </div>
</aside><!-- fixed-col -->
```

css

```
html, body {
        margin: 0;
        height: 100%;
    }

    .fixed-col {
        width: 290px;
        height: 100%;
        position: fixed;
        left: 0;
        background: url(../img/menu-bg.jpg) no-repeat;
        background-size: 100% 100%;
        overflow-y: auto;
        overflow-x: hidden; 
    }

    .fix-wrap {
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
        min-height: 100%;
    }

    .fixed-col-inner {
        height: 100%;
        position: relative;
    }

    .fixed-col-inner h1 {
        margin: 0;
        font: 24px/90px Arial;
        color: #fff;
        margin-left: 30px;
    }

    .menu-button {
        width: 36px;
        height: 32px;
        position: absolute;
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
        right: 30px;
        top: 30px;
        border-radius: 2px;
    }

    .menu-button a {
        display: block;
        background: url(../img/menu-button-bg.png) center center no-repeat;
        width: 36px;
        height: 32px;
    }

    .menu-button:hover {
        background: #5b5c5b;
    }

    .fixed-col-inner input {
        width: 230px;
        height: 40px;
        border: none;
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
        outline: none;
        color: #c4c4c4;
        margin-left: 30px;
        padding: 0 40px 0 15px;
    }

    button.search-button {
        width: 17px;
        height: 17px;
        display: block;
        border: none;
        outline: none;
        background: url(../img/search-icon.png) center center no-repeat;
        position: absolute;
        right: 46px;
        top: 101px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .fav-wrap {
        text-align: center;
        margin: 25px 30px 0;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #51504f;
        padding-bottom: 30px;
        background: url(../img/star.png) 30% 7% no-repeat;
    }

    a.fav {
        display: inline-block;
        padding-left: 27px;
        color: #fff;
        text-decoration: none;
        font: 14px Calibri;
    }

    a.fav:hover {
        text-decoration: underline;
    }

    .menu-side {
        padding-top: 25px;
    }

    .menu-side img {
        max-width: 31px;
        max-height: 31px;
        display: block;
        margin: 0 auto 10px;
    }

    .username {
        display: table;
        margin: 0 auto;
        font: 14px Calibri;
        color: #fff;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    .username:hover, .logout:hover {
        text-decoration: underline;
    }

    .logout {
        display: table;
        margin: 8px auto 0;
        font: 12px Calibri;
        color: #84e5df;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    .main-nav {
        margin: 15px 0 0 0;
        padding: 0;
        list-style-type: none;
    }

    .main-nav li {
        display: block;
    }

    .main-nav li:hover {
        background: #4d4d4d;
    }

    .main-nav li a {
        font: 14px/39px Calibri;
        color: #f5f5f5;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: block;
        background: url(../img/paper-empty.png) left center no-repeat;
        padding-left: 30px;
        margin-left: 30px;
    }

    .main-nav li a.add {
        background: url(../img/paper-add.png) left center no-repeat;
    }

    .last-li {
        margin: 15px 30px 0;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #51504f;
    }

    .second-nav {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        list-style-type: none;
        max-height: 0px;
        overflow: hidden;
        opacity: 0;
        visibility: hidden;
        transition: all .5s ease;
    }

    .second-nav li {
        display: block;
    }

    .second-nav li:first-child {
        margin-top: 15px;
    }

    .second-nav li:hover {
        background: #4d4d4d;
    }

    .second-nav li a {
        font: bold 16px/39px Calibri;
        color: #f5f5f5;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: block;
        padding-left: 30px;
    }

    .menu-side:hover .second-nav{
        max-height: 5000px;
        opacity: 1;
        visibility: visible;
        overflow: visible;
    }

    .social {
        margin: 30px 30px 0 30px; 
        padding: 0;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .social li {
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
        margin: 0 5px;
    }

    .social li a {
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

    .facebook a {
        background: url(../img/facebook-ico.png) center center no-repeat;
        display: block;
        width: 10px;
        height: 18px;
    }

    .vk a {
        background: url(../img/vk-ico.png) center center no-repeat;
        display: block;
        width: 24px;
        height: 14px;
    }

    .second-nav a:hover + .hidden-nav, .hidden-nav:hover {
        width: 200px;
        height: 100%;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 290px;
        background: black;
    }
```

The `.hidden-nav` appears when hovering his parent `<li>`. But when browsers height is too small - appears vertical scrollbar in sidebar. I need it, but becouse of it I cant hover my block `.hidden-nav` :) Is there any way to hide scrollbar of my sidebar, but still its be scrollable?)

Here is [JsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/20zxfn6r/3/). Hover on img and you can see the dropdown menu. Hover on "HOVER ME AND SEE" and you can see problem))

Comment: Well one thing you could do, is position `.hidden-nav` about 20px more to the left, so that it will cover the scrollbar. And if you don’t want that to have any visible effect, then you could wrap it into an additional container element that takes care of the positioning, and has a 20px transparent border on the left – like this, http://jsfiddle.net/20zxfn6r/6/ Only small drawback – the scrollbar will not be usable if you move the mouse from the right side onto the scrollbar, because it will still be covered by the transparent border.

Comment: OK, added as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you could do, is position `.hidden-nav` about 20px more to the left, so that it will cover the scrollbar.

And if you don’t want that to have any visible effect, then you could wrap it into an additional container element that takes care of the positioning, and has a 20px transparent border on the left – like this, http://jsfiddle.net/20zxfn6r/6

Only small drawback – the scrollbar might not be usable if you move the mouse from the right side onto the scrollbar, because it will still be covered by the transparent border.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can do that by changing these 3 CSS classes.

```
.fixed-col {
    width: 290px;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    background: url(../img/menu-bg.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.fix-wrap {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;

}

.fixed-col-inner {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    padding-right: 15px; /* Increase this value for cross-browser compatibility */
}
```

Check out this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/20zxfn6r/7/)..

Comment: In fiddle it dont work, but I understand what you mean. Thank.

Comment: It appears horizontal scrollbar for sidebar, and I cant move mouse to .hidden-nav )